# com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.local' timed out after PT0.5S

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, connection-timeout

When I am trying to run my Java application which is trying to connect to the Cassandra I am getting the below exception:

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system.local' timed out after PT0.5S

    DriverConfigLoader configBuilder = DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
                .withClass(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_CLASS, PlainTextAuthProvider.class)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_USER_NAME, user)
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.AUTH_PROVIDER_PASSWORD, pass)
                .withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_WARN_INIT_ERROR, false)
                .withInt(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_MAX_REQUESTS, 32768)
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).build();

        try {
            cqlSession = CqlSession.builder().addContactPoints(hostsList).withKeyspace(keyspace)
                    .withLocalDatacenter(dataCenter).withConfigLoader(configBuilder).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("CassandraConfig >> Unable to connect to database {}", e);
        }
```

Comment: Please include any code or specific configurations that may contribute towards a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 0.5S means 0.5 seconds. Maybe it's too low for your use-case. Try to increase it in the reference.conf/application.conf files (or the configuration file that you're using).

Default configuration can be found in the reference.conf file of the DataStax driver JAR file.